# Find low level price of any day session 60 min after market open

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to recover the open values ​​of the second intraday daily candle. so if for example I am on 30min, I would like the open of the candle that has just closed at 10:30, I need it to place a line at that level, I would also like this line to have the entire daily session as its length, instead putting on x2=bar_index+1 he brings it to me already on the second candle of the following day

I attach the code below of the tests I did

so I thought I'd solve it by asking for it to open after 60min but I don't know how.

with v1 solution(yellow line) it seems to work but then it blocks me after about 56 lines per day, as you can see I don't have any more in the graph. is it as if it were creating duplicates, multiplying them by the intraday bars (12) until it reaches around 500? what do you think?

I tried to put simple lines at the openings of the day and it shows me 500 in fact

same problem
while with this other solution (orange line)

and this v3 version also doesn't work
(greenline)

[graph show lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQkJX.png)

code:

```
//@version=5
indicator('Custom Gap Indicator', max_lines_count = 500, shorttitle='CGI', overlay=true)

//var 1
var open1030 = 0.0
open1030 := (hour== 10 and minute == 00) ? open : open1030
line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=open1030, x2=bar_index+1, y2=open1030, width=6, color=color.yellow)


// var 2
var float openv2_1030 = na

newDay = ta.change(time("D"))
if newDay

    openv2_1030 := time + (60 * 60 * 1000) ? open : openv2_1030
    line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=openv2_1030, x2=bar_index+11, y2=openv2_1030, width=3, color=color.orange)


//var3
var float openv3_1030 = na
openv3_1030 := time(timeframe.period, "1000-1030:23456") ? open: openv3_1030
line.new(x1 = bar_index,y1 = openv3_1030,x2 = bar_index+1,y2 = openv3_1030,color = color.green,width = 2)
```

thanks to whoever can help me

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for. This will draw a line from the second candles open and extend to the last bar on the chart

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500)
var firstBar = 0
var secondBar = 0
var secondOpen = 0.0
var line openLine = na

newDay = ta.change(time('D'))
firstBar := newDay ? bar_index : firstBar
secondBar := bar_index == firstBar + 1 ? time : secondBar
secondOpen := bar_index == firstBar + 1 ? open : secondOpen

if barstate.islast
    (openLine[1]).delete()
    openLine := line.new(secondBar, secondOpen, chart.right_visible_bar_time,secondOpen,xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```